# installing GitLab on VPS running Parallels Plesk

Tags: git, svn, vps, gitlab, plesk

I'm thinking about installing GitLab Community Edition on my VPS which is currently also running svn & Parallels Plesk (git should eventually replace svn). The VPS hosts a couple of websites, none of which carry heavy load.

VPS specs:
CentOS 6.5 
RAM 2Gb
CPU Intel Xeon 2,3Ghz

I'm wondering if [the installation](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) of GitLab could somehow mess up Plesk or will both work flawlessly alongside each other?

also: how do bind the domain name to the server? i.e. git.myserver.com
should not be done through plesk, right?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a new subdomain in Plesk e.g. `gitlab.domain.com`.
2. Remove all files under: `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/gitlab.domain.com/`
3. Add a new file `gitlab.conf` to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` with the following content:

   ```
   upstream gitlab {
       # for manual installation
       server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
       # for omnibus installation
       server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket;
   }
   ```
4. in Plesk select Websites & Domains > your subdomain > Webserver Settings - remove all ticks under "nginx settings" and add the following code to "Additional nginx directives"

   ```
   location ~ / {
       # serve static files from defined root folder;.
       # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
       # for manual installation
       root /home/git/gitlab/public;
       # for omnibus installation
       root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
       try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
     }

     # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
     # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
     location @gitlab {
       proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
       proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
       proxy_redirect     off;

   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

   proxy_pass http://gitlab;


   }
   ```
5. Save this settings and reboot your server

Note: Maybe you have to change some permissions - see also https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2071

Comment: thanks Nilo !

one problem:  I can't add the directive you posted above, instead I get the following error from plesk:

Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "root" directive is duplicate in /var/www/vhosts/system/gitlab.mydomain.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:7 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Nevermind the comment above, I forgot to remove the line for manual installation :( But shouldn't I change 'proxy_pass http://gitlab;' to my own url ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it helped me get my Gitlab instance installed on Ubuntu 20 LTS with Plesk Obsidian 18. For me to make it work, I had to also edit `Tools & Settings -> Security / Web Application Firewall (ModSecurity)` and add the ID 210492 to the exception list. Otherwise the FW forbids access to git itself.

Comment: upstream servers should start with `unix://`, with two slashes

Answer (score 1):

With GitLab 8, gitlab-git-http-server was introduced, and the old nginx configuration used for version 7 must be changed.

I just found the best tutorial around here: http://www.nullalo.com/en/install-and-configure-gitlab-with-plesk-12-on-centos-6/.

It covers both version 7 and 8 of GitLab, with CentOS v6.5, Plesk 12 and Nginx... that saved my day!

Comment: You're welcome, @DiederikVanRemoortere. Moreover, the article has been updated to work with latest GitLab version 8.2.3 (introducing gitlab-workhorse) too!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you use the omnibus installer for CentOS 6.5.  One thing to know is that Gitlab has a lot of dependencies and some could conflict.  Check and make sure.

For example, it uses Postgresql as the database.  If you already have a local copy installed, you'll need to setup a custom gitlab configuration file to tell it to run it's copy of postgresql on a different port.

Documentation on how to make that gitlab configuration file is pretty much non-existent. It took me a lot of effort to figure it out.  If you find you need to tweak some settings, I can dig up the config I built as an example.

Example config:

```
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

external_url "http://gitlab.example.com:80"
# Shell
gitlab_shell['git_data_directory']      = "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data"
# Rails
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_repos_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']   = 22
gitlab_rails['internal_api_url']        = "http://gitlab.example.com:9001"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_host']             = "gitlab.example.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_port']             = 80
gitlab_rails['db_port']                 = 5432
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features_visibility_level'] = "internal"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features_visibility_level'] = "internal"
# LDAP
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled']  = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_host']     = "ldap.example.com"
gitlab_rails['ldap_port']     = 10389
gitlab_rails['ldap_base']     = "DC=example,DC=com"
gitlab_rails['ldap_method']   = "plain"
gitlab_rails['ldap_uid']      = "uid"
gitlab_rails['ldap_bind_dn']  = ""
gitlab_rails['ldap_password'] = ""
# SMTP
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable']     = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address']    = "smtp.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port']       = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name']  = "example"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password']   = "example"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain']     = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'admin@example.com'
#
unicorn['port']     = 9001
unicorn['user']     = 'gitlab-www'
postgresql['port']  = 5432

ci_external_url 'http://gitlab-ci.example.com'
```

Comment: thanks for your comment Chris, No other postgres db running that I know of. I followed the installation instructions, all went well, no errors. but gitlab is not showing up on the domain. I guess this is because apache is receiving the request instead of nginx. shouldn't I configure gitlab / ngnix to run on a different port?

Comment: There is a configuration parameter you can use to set the port that it runs on and do a `reconfigure` operation to set that as the port.

Comment: hi Chris, would you mind sharing the config you came up with? I followed your suggestion to use the omnibus installer. And also followed Nilo's suggestion to configure Plesk. I'm currently getting an nginx bad gateway error when I open the page...